# Convert indentations across all files in bulk

Tags: windows, regex, code-beautification

Is there a tool to convert indentations across all specified text files? From tabs to spaces, spaces to tabs, 2 spaces to 4 spaces, etc.? I mainly need it for JavaScript files.

I use [Sublime Text](http://www.sublimetext.com/), and the conversion can be done with that program [on a per-file basis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14773271/how-to-fix-convert-space-indentation-in-sublime-text/14773274#14773274), but I want to do this in bulk for many files.

A simple [search and replace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20675237/converting-spaces-to-tabs-in-multiple-files-sublime-text-2/20675429) has side effects. It replaces tabs/spaces *everywhere*, even those that are *not* for indentation purpose. I want it to affect indentation *only*.

A [complex regex might be the solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12807987/regex-to-change-the-number-of-spaces-in-an-indent-level) but it doesn't work with any tools I've tried it in so far (grepWin, Notepad++, Sublime).

A command-line tool would be acceptable, as long as it works in Windows cmd or Git bash.

It should be gratis.

Thanks for the question @mguassa!

Comment: Do you need it for a particular programming language? Do you use an IDE? Would it be OK a command line tool? Does the program need to be gratis? It can all help to find a more targeted solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've tried different solutions, from regular expressions in Sublime Text to
dedicated JavaScript beautifiers such as [js-beautify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/js-beautify) and [UglifyJS2](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2) (with the `--beautify` option). Regarding regex, it seemed too complicated to find an expression that could cover all the cases you mentioned, while for the other two tools, they look good, but even with specific options, they changed more than just indentation and needed some extra work for bulk processing.

In the end, the tool I suggest to use is **[Artistic Style](http://astyle.sourceforge.net/)** (a.k.a. AStyle):

> Artistic Style is a source code indenter, formatter, and beautifier
>   for the C, C++, C++/CLI, Objective‑C, C# and Java programming
>   languages.

It's a command line tool, free, open-source ([here's the SourceForge page](http://sourceforge.net/projects/astyle/)), cross-platform, [well-documented](http://astyle.sourceforge.net/astyle.html)  and easy to setup and configure. It's not specific to JavaScript, but for what I could test it works well with that programming language too. **The bulk processing is a feature of the program.**

Here are some use cases based on your requirements:

**From tabs to spaces:** `AStyle.exe C:\tmp\*.js --indent=spaces=2`

**From spaces to tabs:** `AStyle.exe C:\tmp\*.js --indent=force-tab`

**From 2 spaces to 4 spaces:** `AStyle.exe C:\tmp\*.js --indent=spaces=4`

More options are available to:

- prevent the creation of a backup file
- run recursively in all subdirectories
- perform a dry run
- apply several code formattings, not just indentation
- etc.

In addition, on the website, you can have a look at the page dedicated to [ready-to-use scripts](http://astyle.sourceforge.net/scripts.html) and the list of [GUI programs/plugins](http://astyle.sourceforge.net/links.html) that use AStyle (among them there's also a Sublime Text plugin, which I haven't tried but I presume it cannot process files in bulk).

Comment: What's the guarantee that after astyle has had a whack at your source code, that it it still works properly?  If one is going to run this on hundreds of files, you don't want to find out the hard way.